# firebase ml kit face detection, draw rectangle when there is no any face why?

Tags: android, firebase-mlkit

I downloaded the prebuild firebase based ml kit for face-detection from the following link->
https://github.com/ankitjamuar/android-firebase-mlkit

It is right, but in some cases, it draws the rectangle box when there is no face, like look in this captures screen shot->

[image]

Comment: how can I solve this? pls, help.

Comment: Could you try the https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/ml/vision/face/FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions#ACCURATE?